# Bottleneck in multiprocessing.Process (or ProcessPoolExecutor)?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, overhead

I am implementing a large sized (2^(10~) x 2^(10~)) matrix computation code with python.
To reduce the execution time, I applied multiprocessing such as concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor and multiprocessing.Process.

By the way, I couldn't get any improved result.
I mean, a single process code completes the computation much more faster than the parallel code.
Obviously, both codes share the core computation function composed of kronecker product, matrix-matrix multiplication, matrix-vector multiplication.

To know the reason, I checked the consumed time for each part, and I found that returning the result from each sub-process dominates the execution time.

For example, I created 2 sub-processes for matrix computation.
In each sub-process, it takes only 0.5 ~ 0.6 seconds, but in main process it takes around 40 seconds to gather the result after starting each process.

This is the reduced time by applying multiprocessing.Pipe than multiprocessing.Queue.
When I used Queue previously, a longer time is required for gathering the result.

The result created in each sub-process is a large size matrix of 2^10~ x 2^10~ .

What is the best approach to speed up the data return part in multiprocessing code ?

Comment: Please share your code so that people could spot its bottlenecks, if any.

Comment: Transfering that amount of data between processes of any kind will take some time. I don't see so many options. Maybe you could return single calculation results (a float or int number) and directly write in a share dictionary?

Comment: @RaJa My code usually returns a vector of size 2^10~. It takes non-trivial time even longer than dot operation. Since this post, I recently tested shared memory with an expectation that the returning result time can be reduced in remarkably, but I am not sure .. i am still testing.. the approach for a general case.